# Get $this->Auth->user('id') in user model cakephp

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I want a working on a changepassword module. I want to check the user current password from database if it is same as entered by user. I have defined a $validate array as follows.

```
`'old_password' => array(
                'minLength' => array(
                    'rule' => array('minLength', 1),
                    'message' => 'Current Password is  required'
                ),
                'oldPass' => array(
                    'rule' => array('oldPass',array('old_password')),
                    'message' => 'Current Password is  invalid'
                )
            ),`
```

and have defined a method to check the current password

```
`function oldPass($data){
        if(!empty($data['old_password'])) {
            $valid = false;
            $userData = $this->Auth->user(); // here I am getting error 
            $oldPass = Security::hash(Configure::read('Security.salt') . $data['old_password']);
            if ($userData['User']['password'] == $oldPass) {
                $valid = true;
            }
            return $valid;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }`
```

Here is the error I am getting 
 Undefined property: User::$Auth [APP\models\user.php, line 194]
Fatal error: Call to a member function user() on a non-object in

Basically All I want to match the current password with the password entered by user

I am using 
    $this->User->validates() to validate. and to get error messages I am using $this->set('validationErrorsArray', $this->User->invalidFields());

Please help me how can I get the current logged in user id in model.

Comment: I solved this problem by using the code example given [link]http://www.ninjacodermonkey.co.uk/2010/10/obtaining-user-id-in-model-validation-cakephp/ [/link]

Answer (score 23):

There is a dry approach:

```
$uid = CakeSession::read("Auth.User.id");
```

**Note** that this is only for CakePHP 2.x - and still shouldn't be done.
Usually you pass the session data you need into the model layer explicitly .

In 3.x you cannot statically access the session anymore, there you definitely need to pass the data into the model layer.

Comment: Just don't forget to add `App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource')` at the top of the model file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have integrated auth component then you have to get current user by following:

```
$user = $this->Session->read("Auth.User");
$this->User->id = $user['id'];
$userData = $this->User->read();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the username by

```
$_SESSION['Auth']['user']['username']
```

Comment: This would work, but the Cookbook says "Usage of $_SESSION is generally avoided in CakePHP". see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html